# HTML Form not submitting all Data

Tags: php, html, forms

Hey just having a bit of an odd issue, just looking to see if anyone can spot anything obvious here. I have a form that is submitting back to the same page, which is fine, however it is only submitting back the from "Select Group" to "Staff Member" and then the submit and hidden value and not the checkboxes in between. Just at a loss as to why. Let me know if any other details are needed.

Any help would be hugely appreicated!

```
<div class="maincontent">
  <div class="maincontentinner">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span6">
        <div class="widgetbox">
          <h4 class="widgettitle">Enter programme information</h4>
          <div class="widgetcontent">
          <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit_pressed']))
            {

                $Form_Group = $_POST['group'];
                $Form_Date = $_POST['date'];
                $Form_Start = $_POST['S_time'];
                $Form_Finish = $_POST['F_time'];
                $Form_Staff = $_POST['staff'];
                $Form_Arts = $_POST['Arts'];
                $Form_Media = $_POST['Media'];
                $Form_Personal = $_POST['Personal_Development'];
                $Form_Training = $_POST['Training_Support'];
                $Form_Youth = $_POST['Youth_In_Action'];
                $Form_After = $_POST['After_Schools'];
                $Form_Peer = $_POST['Peer_Education'];
                $Form_Drop = $_POST['Drop_In_Centre'];
                $Form_Arranged = $_POST['One_To_One_Arranged'];
                $Form_Casual = $_POST['One_To_One_Casual'];
                $Form_Residential = $_POST['Residentials'];
                $Form_Kayaking = $_POST['Kayaking'];
                $Form_Bike = $_POST['Bike'];
                $Form_HillWalking = $_POST['Hill_Walking'];
                $Form_Multi = $_POST['Multi_Sports'];

                foreach($_POST['members'] as $value)
                {
                    echo 'Checked: '.$value.'';
                }


            }
          ?>
            <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
                <fieldset>
              <p>
                <label>Select Group</label>
                <span class="field">
                <select name="group" class="uniformselect">
                  <option value="">Choose One</option>
                  <?php 
                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `GROUP` ORDER BY Group_Name ASC");      

                    //while loop through each of the rows
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
                    {  

                        //set variables from the rows
                        $Group_ID = $row['Group_ID'];
                        $Group_Name = $row['Group_Name'];
                ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $Group_ID; ?>"><?php echo "$Group_Name"; ?></option>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
                </select>
                </span> </p>
              <div class="par">
                <label>Date Picker</label>
                <span class="field">
                <input id="datepicker" type="date" name="date" class="input-small" />
                </span> </div>
              <div class="par">
                <label>Start Time</label>
                <div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker">
                  <input id="timepicker1" type="time" class="input-small" name="S_time" />
                  <span class="add-on"><i class="iconfa-time"></i></span> </div>
              </div>
              <div class="par">
                <label>Finish Time</label>
                <div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker">
                  <input id="timepicker1" type="time" class="input-small" name="F_time" />
                  <span class="add-on"><i class="iconfa-time"></i></span> </div>
              </div>

              <label>Staff Member</label>
              <span class="field">
              <select name="staff" class="uniformselect">
                <option value="">Choose One</option>
                <?php 
                 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM STAFF ORDER BY STAFF_FNAME ASC");      

                //while loop through each of the rows
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
                {  

                //set variables from the rows
                    $Staff_ID = $row['Staff_ID'];
                    $Staff_FName = $row['Staff_FName'];
                    $Staff_SName = $row['Staff_SName'];
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $Staff_ID; ?>"><?php echo "$Staff_FName $Staff_SName"; ?></option>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
              </select>
              </span> </p>
              <br /><br />
              <p>
              <label></label>
              <span class="field">
              </span>
              </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="span6">
        <div class="widgetbox">
          <h4 class="widgettitle">Select applicable programme(s)</h4>
          <div class="widgetcontent">
              <span class="formwrapper">
              <input type="checkbox" name="Media" />
              Media <br />
              <input type="checkbox" name="Arts" />
              Arts <br />
              <input type="checkbox" name="Personal_Development" />
              Personal Development<br />
              <input type="checkbox" name="Training_Support" />
              Training Support <br />
              <input type="checkbox" name="Youth_In_Action" />
              Youth In Action <br />
              <input type="checkbox" name="After_Schools" />
              After Schools <br />
              <input type="checkbox" name="Peer_Education" />
              Peer Education <br />
              <input type="checkbox" name="Drop_In_Centre" />
              Drop In Centre <br />
              <input type="checkbox" name="One_To_One_Arranged" />
              One To One (Arranged)<br />
              <input type="checkbox" name="One_To_One_Casual" />
              One To One (Casual)<br />
              <input type="checkbox" name="Residentials" />
              Residentials <br />
              <input type="checkbox" name="Kayaking" />
              Kayaking <br />
              <input type="checkbox" name="Bike" />
              Bike <br />
              <input type="checkbox" name="Hill_Walking" />
              Hill Walking <br />
              <input type="checkbox" name="Multi_Sports" />
              Multi Sports <br />
              </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="widgetbox">
        <h4 class="widgettitle">Enter participating members</h4>
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // dynamic table
    jQuery('#dyntable').dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aaSortingFixed": [[0,'asc']],
        "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {
            jQuery.uniform.update();
        }
    });

    jQuery('#dyntable2').dataTable( {
        "bScrollInfinite": true,
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "sScrollY": "300px"
    });



});
```

```
            <table id="dyntable" class="table table-striped responsive">
                <!--table table-bordered responsive
                <colgroup>
                    <col class="con0" style="align: center;/>
                    <col class="con1" />
                    <col class="con0" />
                    <col class="con1" />
                    <col class="con0" />
                    <col class="con1" />
                    <col class="con0" />
                    <col class="con1" />
                    <col class="con0" />
                    <col class="con1" />
                    <col class="con0" />
                    <col class="con1" />
                    <col class="con0" />
                    <col class="con1" />
                </colgroup>-->
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th class="head0 nosort"><input type="checkbox" class="checkall" /></th>
                        <th class="head0">M-ID</th>
                        <th class="head1">Name</th>
                        <th class="head0">Surname</th>
                        <th class="head1">Gender</th>                            
                        <th class="head0">Address</th>
                        <th class="head1">Postcode</th>
                        <th class="head0">Contact</th>
                        <th class="head1">Email</th>
                        <th class="head0">MedCon</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
    <?php 

    //set up the query
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MEMBER ORDER BY MEMBER_FNAME ASC");     

    //while loop through each of the rows
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
    {  

    //set variables from the rows
        $Member_ID=$row['Member_ID'];
        $Member_FName=$row['Member_FName'];
        $Member_SName=$row['Member_SName'];
        $Member_Gender=$row['Member_Gender'];
        $Member_Address=$row['Member_Address'];
        $Member_Postcode=$row['Member_Postcode'];
        $Member_ContactNo=$row['Member_ContactNo'];
        $Member_Email=$row['Member_Email'];
        $Member_Medcon=$row['Member_MedCon'];


    ?>  

                      <td class="aligncenter">
                        <span class="center">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="members[]" value="<?php echo "$Member_ID"; ?>" />
                        </span>
                      </td>
                        <td><?php echo $Member_ID ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $Member_FName ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $Member_SName ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $Member_Gender ?></td>                            
                        <td><?php echo $Member_Address ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $Member_Postcode ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $Member_ContactNo ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $Member_Email ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $Member_Medcon ?></td>                                                
                    </tr>
     <?php
    }
    ?>

                </tbody>
            </table>
            <br />
            <div align="right">
            <input type="hidden" value="TRUE" name="submit_pressed">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Comment: so what is the problem ?

Comment: So we have to `review your code` and find your `problem`? If your `remaining fields` are working the `remove them`.

Comment: What I was asking is why the checkboxes in the middle of the form aren't being sent with the post data, the reason I posted all of the code is I thought it might help as I personally could not see a reason for that! The other fields are posting fine except the checkboxes, As I said in the text above the code, where I explained where in the code was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your checkboxes set up wrong. Should be something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="programs[]" value="Media" />
```

So when the user selects multiple checkboxes they will be put into $_POST[ 'programs' ] rather than trying to access each one individually.

Comment: or `data[<?php echo $Member_ID ?>][programs]` to keep data together

Comment: Ok perfect I'll give you a try! :) Its just confusing me because in Chrome's inspector, none of the checkboxes are sent in the Form data at all and seem to be inaccessible. Hopefully This might fix it! Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Just thought I'd give an update, I tried you're answer which incidentally makes my life simpler however it didn't solve the issue. It turns out the widget boxes in the template are causing the issue, and I need to look into the jquery/CSS which must be causing the problem, however I think the simplest solution might be to put them all in one widget box and create new divs from scratch.